# zend_translate with zend framework 2 possible to use

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-translate

I was looking at the documentation for Zend Framework after trying to figure out why I was getting `no class found` on `zend_translate` class after downloading the latest version (2.2.2).

Then, I noticed that the only documentation for it on the zend website is from version 1. Did they remove `zend_translate` from version 2? Is it possible to use `zend_translate` on version 2? If not, is it recommended and safe to go to the lower version? Maybe it's just under a different name but I don't see the whole functionality of `zend_translate` in the new documentation.

[This](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.html) is the only documentation for it (1.12)

Answer (score 1):

A little effort to solve this kind of question alone would help ;)

The Documentation you linked has a dropdown leading to the [2.2 Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/index.html). In this one you'll find pretty much at the top the topic [Styling and Translations](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/styling-and-translations.html), that will you a quick introduction into the [Zend\I18n](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/index.html#zend-i18n)-Component.

Comment: that's not the same thing as zend_translate

Comment: Correct, it is a better thing, read the docs or come back with concrete problems we can provide solutions for ;)

Comment: `zend_translate` is only part of ZF1. As ZF2 has been rewritten, `Zend\I18n` is the new name for translations. You cannot use `zend_translate` with ZF2 to answer your question directly.

Comment: @Sam thanks , but there is not explicit doc link mentioning Zend-translate(zf2) = I18n(zf2).